# How do I get LLDB to find the source code when building Tup variants?

Tags: lldb, tup

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968721/lldb-not-showing-source-code), I am unable to get LLDB to display the actual source code when debugging.

Thanks to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36973557/926705) on that question, I have traced the problem to how Tup builds variants (e.g. debug, production etc):

1. It works in a subdirectory per-variant
2. It *does not* copy the source into the subdirectory
3. It *does* build all outputs (`.o` files and the executable itself) in the subdirectory

Because of this, LLDB can't find the original source files when debugging.

So my question is: how can I either coerce Tup to feed different paths in to the build process or tell LLDB what is actually going on?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this in two parts:

**1. Get Tup to use accurate paths**

Firstly, so that the executable refers to the `.o` files at their actual location, Tup must be made to run in a chroot ([more info here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tup-users/lldb/tup-users/fKIaQ_arCWQ/sTTOcvgwwPUJ), and [in the docs](http://gittup.org/tup/manual.html#lbAG)). This is done by putting `c` after a caret in the Tup command.

So my build commands went from something like

```
: foreach code/*.cpp |> ^o compile %f^ $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) %f -o %o |> %B.o {code_object_files}
```

to

```
: foreach code/*.cpp |> ^oc compile %f^ $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) %f -o %o |> %B.o {code_object_files}`
```

This got the right paths into the executable, but the `.o` files still referred to the source files as though they were in the build subdirectory, rather than the main directory, leading to:

**2. Tell LLDB where to look for the source**

So LLDB thinks the source is at `/Users/leo/project/subdirectory/code` but they are actually at `/Users/leo/project/code`. This is solved as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973633/lldb-equivalent-of-gdb-directory-command-for-specifying-source-search-path) by telling LLDB to substitute one path for another:

```
(lldb) settings set target.source-map /Users/leo/project/subdirectory /Users/leo/project
```

(This didn't seem to work with relative paths, which is a shame as it means a per-dev-machine solution is needed. If anyone knows of a solution that would work regardless of where the project is then let me know!)

You can also automate this by having LLDB source a file with this line in: `lldb -s path/to/lldb/config/file`.