# No debug info / source code with LLDB on OSX

Tags: macos, clang, dwarf

I'm not able to see source code in lldb, despite trying to the advice of [LLDB not showing source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968721/lldb-not-showing-source-code)

I've boiled this down to a simple C++17 program that is compiled with the following command. I'm running on OSX with clang 7.0.1 that I've compiled myself from source, but my lldb is the XCode-installed one (this may be a problem?).

Here's my compile command:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -march=native -Wall -g -O0  main.cpp -o main
```

Note that main/main.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF is created when I compile and that seems fine.

One clear issue, though, is that debug info is not in the binary and the object file can't be found at all:

```
$ dsymutil main
warning: (x86_64) /var/folders/c1/vxvr6h9x10b8dbsxhh6nx05h0000gn/T/main-43ca25.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
```

I was under the impression that I can just compile with debug info (via `-g`) and have everything "just work" but that's clearly not the case.

How can I get debug symbols to work so I can use lldb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by removing the `-flto` linker flag that I didn't realize I had on. Apparently, when LTO is enabled, debugging symbols do not work.